# Can we use Botium CLI for testing a mobile voice app in SauceLabs?

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot, botium-box

Can we leverage Botium speech processing and Botium CLI to test a mobile voice based App (built on Rasa)?
The idea is to test the app on SauceLabs or any cloud service. Most documentations are around Alexa Skills.

This article by Florian Treml is nice but it uses Botium-box and is a different use case than ours.
https://medium.com/swlh/beginners-guide-to-automated-voice-app-testing-4596dd9130fd

Is there a working example that we can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Upfront, most things that work in Botium Box are working in Botium Core and Botium CLI as well, but it requires more setup effort.*

When testing a chatbot, doing End2End-Tests on Appium at the very beginning is a bad idea - I wrote about the reasons [here](https://floriantreml.medium.com/upskilling-test-engineers-for-chatbot-projects-44c96e4f26a0).

I recommend to start testing on the Rasa API level.

And to answer your question: right now it is not possible out-of-the-box with the Botium Webdriver connector to send and receive voice - this requires customization, and it heavily depends on implementation details of the app under test.

UPDATE

For testing Rasa on API Level with audio input, I wrote a [blog article](https://floriantreml.medium.com/giving-a-voice-to-rasa-with-botium-speech-1c65a7513bdf) how to add voice capabilities in the Rasa processing pipeline. And this scenario can be tested with the Botium Socket.io connector, there is even a Rasa sample available based on the mentioned article: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-simple-socketio/tree/master/samples/rasa

Comment: The medium article was an interesting read. Thanks @Florian.


I was thinking, if we do not use the Botium - WebdriverIO connector (meaning, if we eliminate the end to end testing for the time being) and use the Botium-Rasa connector, can we still pass a wav file or any other voice machanism as a convo file to Botium tests.

Comment: This is possible, but as Rasa has (afaik) no default API for receiving audio files, maybe there are customizations required - see update of my response.